# Power BI Filtering the graph based on the bin

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to make a graph that re-evaluates a items 'status' based on the bin of the graph. Each bin represents a two week date range. I want the graph to display atleast 6 bins and determine the number of items which fall into each of the below categories.

New definition: if opened in the range of the bin it is in then new

Closed definition: if closed in the range of the bin it is in then closed

Active definition: if (opened on date is before the bin it is in) and (closed on data is either null or closed on date is after the bin it is in) then active

Closed on date and opened on date are columns I have.

The issue I'm having is that for each bin it needs to re-check these definitions and then display it on one graph.

Is this something Power Bi is capable of doing and how would I go about doing this? It feels like the measures I make to count the different item types need to take into account the bin date, but I don't know how to do that

Thanks,

In response to a comment:

So i've been able to create the date bins, but I'm having issues with creating the three measures. When I go to write the measure it would look something like this: For the New definition: count (rows) where detected on date falls with the bin range. Then I need to also create a 2nd measure for Active: count (rows) where detected on date falls before the bin range and closed on date is null or after bin range. And a 3rd measure for Closed: count(rows) where closed on date falls within the bin. But there will be 6 bins in the graph and these measures' defintions depend on which bin it is, which I don't know how to include in a measure

Comment: I don't really understand what you need help with. Do you need help creating the dates for the bins? Writing the measure? Or optimizing a current measure? In other words, what have you already tried and what is it you want to achieve, possibly add some pictures as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited the post with more info. The main issue I'm having is creating the measures

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunately I'm nowhere near a computer for a week so I am unable to give you an exact answer but I can give you some directions. Try using a CALCULATE function and play a little bit with the configuration of the filters. Have a look into the ALL and ALLSELECTED functions and possibly EARLIER. there are also plenty of posts here on stack overflow explaining how to have rolling timeframes and all the filtering that comes along with it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will look into those options, honestly I just didn't even know what to search for to get help with this